# service worker can not cache the start url

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

I put the PWA version of my app in the https://www.example.com/app folder. I have tried caching the the start page using the following urls formats (one by one in **FILES_TO_CACHE**) but none of them work

```
"/"
"/app"
"/app/"
"/app/index.php"
"app"
"app/index.php"
"./"
"./app"
```

sw.js:

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'static-cache-v1.2';
const DATA_CACHE_NAME = 'data-cache';

//Those tries and errors go here one by one
const FILES_TO_CACHE = [
    "/" 
];

self.addEventListener('install', (evt) => {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    evt.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Pre-caching offline page');
            return cache.addAll(FILES_TO_CACHE);
        }).then(self.skipWaiting())
    );


});

self.addEventListener('activate', (evt) => {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');

    evt.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => {
                if (key !== CACHE_NAME) {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
                    return caches.delete(key);
                }
            }));
        })
    );

    self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (evt) => {
console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', evt.request.url);
    evt.respondWith(

        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
            return cache.match(evt.request).then(cacheResponse => cacheResponse || fetch(evt.request).then(networkResponse => {
                cache.put(evt.request, networkResponse.clone());
                return networkResponse;
            }));

        }))
});
```

Google chrome lighthouse says:

> start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline

Besides I have to say that service worker is being registered successfully as I get a console message and also the app has base url set in header like this:

```
<base href="https://www.example.com/app/">
```

and this is the code I use to register service worker placed in `https://www.example.com/app/index.php` and receive the success message in console:

```
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {scope: '/app/'})
  .then((reg) => {
    console.log("Web workers work");
  }).catch((error) => {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}  else{
  console.log("No sw available");
  }

</script>
```

Comment: as you try your different versions are you remembering to also update your `CACHE_NAME` as otherwise you aren't "clearing the cache" so any previous mistakes will be carried over.

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing cache name for every test but no success. @GrahamRitchie

Comment: Can you share your code when you are registering the service worker? and it would be good if you can host your app so that we can troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I added the registration code in the question. Thanks @VimalPatel

Comment: Are you using manifest.webmanifest file?

Comment: Yes the manifest is with the above name and mimetype also added and working fine.Chrome lighthouse is totally green expect the home pahe cache. @VimalPatel